# How to remove an element where all descendants are empty

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I would like to remove all the rows from the root where all the columns are empty.

```
<root>
  <row>
    <column></column>
    <column></column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column></column>
    <column>data</column>
  </row>
<root>
```

I have tried xDocument.Descendants("row").Elements("column").Where(e => e.IsEmpty || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value)).Remove();

but end up with

```
<root>
  <column>data</column>
<root>
```

where my desired results are;

```
<root>
  <column></column>
  <column>data</column>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
xDocument.Descendants("row").Where(r => r.Elements().All(e => e.IsEmpty || String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))).Remove()
```